# Run SQL query on dataframe via Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to run sql query on dataframe but do I have to create a view on this dataframe?
Is there any easier way?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
('a', 1, 1), ('a',1, None), ('b', 1, 1),
('c',1, None), ('d', None, 1),('e', 1, 1)
]).toDF('id', 'foo', 'bar')
```

and the query I want to run some complex queries against this dataframe.
For example
I can do

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_view")
df_new = pyspark.sql("select id,max(foo) from temp_view group by id")
```

but do I have to convert it to view first before querying it?
I know there is a dataframe equivalent operation.
The above query is only an example.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
df.select('id', 'foo')
```

This will return a new Spark DataFrame with columns `id` and `foo`.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to run a more complex query against this table.
Above is an example.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the exact operation (s) you're looking to perform?

Comment: Besides converting the dataframe to a view then querying it, do we have different way to run SQL query aginst this dataframe?

Comment: You can explore using `expr` from `pyspark.sql.functions`. More info can be found in the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html?highlight=expr#pyspark.sql.functions.expr

Comment: Thanks. I have also seen under spark document, the spark.sql has been used interchangeably with pyspark.sql, are they the same?
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.exists.html

Comment: Spark SQL is a component of spark. PySpark is an interface for Spark components

Comment: so in the above link,can I use pyspark.createDataFrame() instead?

Comment: No. In the above, `spark` refers to a spark context